# Gradle build of hibernate-core: how to properly add a dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependency-management

I am trying to fork [hibernate-core 4.3.6.Final](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-core) in the following way: remove the package `org.hibernate.annotations` and to add a dependency to `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.0.1.Final` which should provide the named package.

Removing the folder `hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/annotations` was the easy part. After that I made the following change to the gradle build script:

```
diff --git a/hibernate-core/hibernate-core.gradle b/hibernate-core/hibernate-core.gradle
index 767113f..d13d7d6 100644
--- a/hibernate-core/hibernate-core.gradle
+++ b/hibernate-core/hibernate-core.gradle
@@ -22,6 +22,7 @@ dependencies {
     provided( libraries.jacc )
     provided( libraries.validation )
     provided( libraries.classmate )
+    provided( 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.0.1.Final' )

     testCompile( project(':hibernate-testing') )
     testCompile( libraries.validation )
```

As a maven user, I expected this to work instantly. However if I fire `gradlew -p hibernate-core clean build -x test --refresh-dependencies` I get compiler errors such as

```
D:\git\hibernate-orm\hibernate-core\src\main\java\org\hibernate\cfg\Mappings.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
import org.hibernate.annotations.AnyMetaDef;
                                ^
  symbol:   class AnyMetaDef
  location: package org.hibernate.annotations
```

which makes clear that `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.0.1.Final` is missing on the classpath. Indeed if I run gradle with verbose output I can recognize the jar isn't even being downloaded.

Since I don't have any experience with gradle I would appreciate any hints.